# jquery selector issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, jquery-traversing

I have a div which in jquery's document ready I append - using `$("#div id").append('html text')` syntax - with 10 or so more div child elements.

once this is done I try to check the content of the child divs via `alert($(".classname"));` and it comes back with:

```
function(a){if(c.isFunction(a))return this.each(function(b){var d=c(this);d.text(a.call(this,b,d.text()))});if(typeof a!=="object"&&a!==w)return this.empty().append((this[0]&&this[0].ownerDocument||s).createTextNode(a));return c.text(this)}
```

I would have expected it to alert with the html contents of the child divs and not javascript?

full script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // twitter api's base url
        var url="http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&result_type=recent&q=";
        // we'll store the search term here
        var query = "blah";
        // get the json file
        $.getJSON(url+query,function(json){
            // this is where we can loop through the results in the json object
            $.each(json.results,function(i,tweet){
                // this is where we do what we want with each tweet
                $("#results").append('<div class="tweetBox"><span class="unseen">'+tweet.created_at+'</span><div class="tweetImg"><img src="'+tweet.profile_image_url+'" width="48" height="48" /><a class="overbox" href="http://twitter.com/'+tweet.from_user+'/status/'+tweet.id+'"></a></div>'+tweet.text+' ...said '+((new Date().getTime()/1000/60)-(new Date(tweet.created_at))/1000/60).toFixed(0)+' minutes ago</div>');

            });
        });

        $("#results").height(function(){return $(window).height()-204;});
        alert($(".unseen").html());     
    });
</script>

<div id="results"></div>
```

update:
definitely some kind of jquery/javascript race condition going on here, if I replace the alert with `setTimeout(function(){alert($(".unseen").html());},1000);` it returns the text expected.  If I change the timeout pause to 1 millisecond it returns `null` once again.

Not sure of a 'real' workaround for this other than sticking in the delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax calls (like `$.getJSON`) are done asynchronously.

This means that when the jQuery selection is done(at the bottom of the script) the response might not be received yet (still on the way).

You have to move all the code that depends on elements created from the response in the callback function (right after the `$.each(...);`)

Ex:

```
$.getJSON(url+query,function(json){
    // this is where we can loop through the results in the json object
    $.each(json.results,function(i,tweet){
        // this is where we do what we want with each tweet
        $("#results").append('<p>this element is created only when the callback is triggered</p>');
    });
    // do stuff here with all your created elements
    alert('found '+$(".unseen").length+' objects');
});
```

Also note that the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html) function returns the html contents of only the first element in the set.

*EDIT: your timeout trick works because it gives the ajax call the time it needs to complete and trigger the callback function that ads the objects to the DOM.*

See working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/GXRZa/).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
alert($('.classname').html());
```

I don't understand why it returned function text; are you certain that you just had `$('.classname')` in your `alert()` call?  Maybe you had `$('.classname').html` without the final `()`?

Comment: $('.classname').html() returns null and there is definitely text in the span.

Comment: Well perhaps you could post the actual stuff that you're inserting into the document.

Comment: done. happens quite a bit when using selectors in dom ready to be honest

Comment: Most jQuery functions and calls like `$('.cls')` return a jQuery object(i.e. $). 
This is very useful for chaining. Ex: `$('.cls').not('#id').addClass('invisible').hide();`

Somehow in this case the alert showed the `.text` function (either this is something browser specific, because `toString()` should have been the default, or he tried something like `alert($('.cls').text);`).
Anyway, while in development I suggest you use the un-minified version of jQuery (this way you can debug and see more clearly what the problem is).